# Firefox doesn't load local file in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe

I have a file

> file:///C:/Users/7%20Legged%20Spider/Desktop/test.html

When I set it into an iframe

> < iframe src="file:///C:/Users/7%20Legged%20Spider/Desktop/test.html">

The iframe is blank, why is this and how can I fix it

Comment: Where is the file with the iframe located? In the same directory? On the same computer?

Comment: set up a webserver (apache or ngnix) and then load the page as `http://localhost/test.html`

Answer (score 4):

It is because of security issue. You can not bypass it by any mean.

You should not use local file as `href` because of:

- Security problems
- "Unexpected" URLs (not everyone has C:\)
- If you are using it only for development, you may want to upload the file to your server in order to include it.

Comment: What could possibly be the point of this if access to the iframe's content is already blocked by the cross domain rule?

Comment: Side note: yes you can access it by `window.postMessage` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage)