# Displaying a PDF from desktop on a ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I'm in the process of trying to display a PDF that is located to my local machine on an asp.net web page.

I have tried the `iframe` and `embed` tags, but all just keep coming up blank.

I have managed to use the `iframe` to direct to a website, however, it seems a little different when trying to point to my folder on my desktop.

All I need to do is load the PDF on page load, and that is the only thing that will be on this web page.

I cant post any code, as to be truthfully, I have no idea how to do this, and the example I found does not seem to do the trick.

If anyone can help me with an example on how to ref a folder from my desktop, it would be appreciated.

Comment: this is not exactly how we ask questions here. have you tried searching for "how to show local files on a web page " ?

Comment: Providing an embedded document within an IFRAME is not possible due to security reasons. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378983/2298807 for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all web browsers can display PDF documents directly. My Internet Explorer shows PDF documents, but I'm afraid it requires installed Acrobat reader on client machine.
So unless you target to a specific web-browser, you should look for another approach, like converting PDF into HTML and displaying it, or into JPG (which I wouldn't recommend).